# Window Size in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to set size of PowerShell window using a PowerShell script. The code I'm using is

```
$pshost = Get-Host

$psWindow = $pshost.UI.RawUI

$newSize =$psWindow.BufferSize

$newSize.Height = 4000
$newSize.Width = 200

$psWindow.BufferSize = $newSize

$newSize = $psWindow.WindowSize
$newSize.Height = 95
$newSize.Width = 150

$psWindow.WindowSize= $newSize
```

It works fine in most cases, but sometimes I get the error on certain desktop sizes. For example, I tried with 95 and failed with the error below for my desktop screen size 1440x960.

```
Exception setting "WindowSize": "Window cannot be taller than 82.
Parameter name: value.Height
Actual value was 95."
At line:1 char:5
+     $psWindow.WindowSize= $newSize
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
```

Is there a way I can calculate the maximum window size setting on the machine that it is running the script on and set the size of PowerShell window?

Comment: `(get-host).UI.RawUI.MaxWindowSize`?

Comment: Thanks Austin, that gave me the max values

Comment: @user2344145 You should accept Austin French's answer, by far the most correct way to do this

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i did.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your were already on the right course.

```
(Get-Host).UI.RawUI.MaxWindowSize
```

Or more specifically:

```
$height = (Get-Host).UI.RawUI.MaxWindowSize.Height
$width = (Get-Host).UI.RawUI.MaxWindowSize.Width
```

Comment: Thank you. I did it this way so that i dont have to do any extra logic.

Comment: `(Get-Host).UI.RawUI.MaxWindowSize` is NOT the max window size it can be, because it can't exceed the `BufferSize`, but `BufferSize` is changable. see Mathias R. Jessen's answer below

Answer (score 5):

You could attempt to set it to the desired value, and then on error, set it to whatever the error states the max value is. For the Width, set it to the same as the buffer width

```
function Set-ConsoleWindow
{
    param(
        [int]$Width,
        [int]$Height
    )

    $WindowSize = $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize
    $WindowSize.Width  = [Math]::Min($Width, $Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize.Width)
    $WindowSize.Height = $Height

    try{
        $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize = $WindowSize
    }
    catch [System.Management.Automation.SetValueInvocationException] {
        $Maxvalue = ($_.Exception.Message |Select-String "\d+").Matches[0].Value
        $WindowSize.Height = $Maxvalue
        $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize = $WindowSize
    }
}
```

Comment: Ew, the long hard way to skin a cat?

Comment: Testing against MaxWindowSize is definitely better, but I couldn't help myself